# AWS Queue doesn't return MessageAttributeNames in Response

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce, amazon-sqs

Trying to retrieve message attributes from AWS queue but it doesn't return anything in the response.

What i'm making wrong in the request, Here is the aws documentation i followed
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html

Request:

```
https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/123456789012/MyQueue/
?Action=ReceiveMessage
&MaxNumberOfMessages=5
&VisibilityTimeout=15
&AttributeName=All
&MessageAttributeName=All
&Expires=2020-04-18T22%3A52%3A43PST
&Version=2012-11-05
&AUTHPARAMS
```

Response:

```
<ReceiveMessageResponse>
  <ReceiveMessageResult>
    <Message>
      <MessageId>5fea7756-0ea4-451a-a703-a558b933e274</MessageId>
      <ReceiptHandle>
        MbZj6wDWli+JvwwJaBV+3dcjk2YW2vA3+STFFljTM8tJJg6HRG6PYSasuWXPJB+Cw
        Lj1FjgXUv1uSj1gUPAWV66FU/WeR4mq2OKpEGYWbnLmpRCJVAyeMjeU5ZBdtcQ+QE
        auMZc8ZRv37sIW2iJKq3M9MFx1YvV11A2x/KSbkJ0=
      </ReceiptHandle>
      <MD5OfBody>fafb00f5732ab283681e124bf8747ed1</MD5OfBody>
      <Body>This is a test message</Body>
      <Attribute>
        <Name>SenderId</Name>
        <Value>195004372649</Value>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute>
        <Name>SentTimestamp</Name>
        <Value>1238099229000</Value>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute>
        <Name>ApproximateReceiveCount</Name>
        <Value>5</Value>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute>
        <Name>ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp</Name>
        <Value>1250700979248</Value>
      </Attribute>
    </Message>
  </ReceiveMessageResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>b6633655-283d-45b4-aee4-4e84e0ae6afa</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</ReceiveMessageResponse>
```

Comment: If you view the messages in the SQS console, are the message attributes present?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes, i'm able to see it - what i see on console http://take.ms/figkw

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot When i request via aws-cls i'm able to get the message attributes but the problem is with this rest api

Comment: I'm thinking that it may expect `MessageAttributeName.1=All`.  You might try running aws-cli with `--debug` -- I believe this will let you observe the request it generates.

Comment: Tried MessageAttributeName.1=All and MessageAttributeName.1=.*  but still no luck, this is driving me crazy...

Comment: when running cli with --debug it gives me this "message_attribute_names": ['All'] 
http://take.ms/daITC1

Comment: Try using Postman to replicate your request that way you can rule out the rest api being incorrect.